# Despite using 'onChange', why my input looses focus after any key press?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, controlled-component, todoist

I've just started learning React and I'm trying to build a todo list including edit button. I defined an input inside

tags through a condition in  component. but when i click on edit icon to rewrite a task, with the first keypress the focus is gone!

```
import "./index.css";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faDeleteLeft, faPenToSquare } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { useState } from "react";
const todoItems = [
  { description: "Task 1", id: 111, done: false, edit: false },
  { description: "Task 2", id: 222, done: false, edit: false },
  { description: "Task 3", id: 333, done: false, edit: false },
];
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div
      className="
    app"
    >
      <ToDo />
    </div>
  );
}

function ToDo() {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(todoItems);

  function handleAddTask(task) {
    setTasks((tasks) => [...tasks, task]);
  }

  function handleToggleTask(id) {
    setTasks(
      tasks.map((task) =>
        task.id === id ? { ...task, done: !task.done } : task
      )
    );
  }

  function handleDeleteTask(id) {
    setTasks(tasks.filter((task) => task.id !== id));
  }

  function handleEditTask(id) {
    setTasks(
      tasks.map((task) =>
        task.id === id ? { ...task, edit: !task.edit } : task
      )
    );
  }

  const handleSaveEdit = (id, newText) => {
    setTasks(
      tasks.map((task) =>
        task.id === id ? { ...task, description: newText, edit: false } : task
      )
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="todo-container">
      <Header />
      <TodoList
        tasks={tasks}
        onToggleTask={handleToggleTask}
        onDeleteTask={handleDeleteTask}
        onEditTask={handleEditTask}
        onSaveEdit={handleSaveEdit}
      />
      <TodoForm onAddTask={handleAddTask} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Header() {
  return (
    <header className="todo-header">
      <h2>Todo List</h2>
    </header>
  );
}

function TodoList({
  tasks,
  onToggleTask,
  onDeleteTask,
  onEditTask,
  onSaveEdit,
}) {
  return (
    <ul className="todo-list">
      {tasks.map((task) => (
        <TodoItem
          task={task}
          onToggleTask={onToggleTask}
          onDeleteTask={onDeleteTask}
          onEditTask={onEditTask}
          onSaveEdit={onSaveEdit}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

function TodoItem({
  task,
  onToggleTask,
  onDeleteTask,
  onEditTask,
  onSaveEdit,
}) {
  return (
    <li className="todo-item" key={task.id}>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        value={task.done}
        onChange={() => onToggleTask(task.id)}
      />
      {task.edit ? (
        <input
          type="text"
          value={task.description}
          onChange={(e) => onSaveEdit(task.id, e.target.value)}
          style={{ width: "100%", border: "none", outline: "none" }}
        />
      ) : (
        <label className={task.done ? "done-task" : ""}>
          {task.description}
        </label>
      )}
      {!task.edit && (
        <>
          <FontAwesomeIcon
            icon={faPenToSquare}
            style={{ cursor: "pointer", margin: "0 10px" }}
            onClick={() => onEditTask(task.id)}
          />
          <FontAwesomeIcon
            style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
            icon={faDeleteLeft}
            rotation={180}
            onClick={() => onDeleteTask(task.id)}
          />
        </>
      )}
    </li>
  );
}

function TodoForm({ onAddTask }) {
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (description.trim() === "") return;

    const id = crypto.randomUUID();
    const newTask = { description, id, done: false, edit: false };
    console.log(newTask);
    onAddTask(newTask);

    setDescription("");
  }
  return (
    <form className="todo-input" onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Add a new task"
        value={description}
        onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button>Add</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

I've searched but i could not find the same case as mine! Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: You're triggering a re-render every time you update the state of the TaskList through the setters you passed down. Rather than passing setters to a child to maintain state in a parent, you should keep references to those child elements and retrieve their state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's exactly what you do on this line:

```
onChange={(e) => onSaveEdit(task.id, e.target.value)}
```

Which calls this handler, setting `edit: false`:

```
  const handleSaveEdit = (id, newText) => {
    setTasks(
      tasks.map((task) =>
        task.id === id ? { ...task, description: newText, edit: false } : task
      )
    );
  };
```

You have two options:

- Use an uncontrolled input with a "save" button on the side. Once the user is done editing that value, they can click the "save" button, which calls `handleSaveEdit`. `newText` can be obtained by adding a `ref` to the `<input>`. Additionally, you might want to have a "cancel" / "discard change" button.
- Keep using a controlled input and automatically "save" the value as it changes. In this case, you just need a different handler that updates the target task's `description` without changing its `edit` property:

  ```
  const handleEdit = (id, newText) => {
    setTasks(
      tasks.map((task) =>
        task.id === id ? { ...task, description: newText } : task
      )
    );
  };
  ```